# jolt array transform using wildcard

Tags: arrays, json, jolt

I'm using JOLT to transform data from:

```
[{"a" : "a",
  "b" : "b",
  "c" : "c",
  ...},
 {"a" : "a",
  "b" : "b",
  "c" : "c",
  ...}]
```

To:

```
[{"a1" : "a",
  "b1" : "b",
  "c1" : "c",
  ...},
 {"a1" : "a",
  "b1" : "b",
  "c1" : "c",
  ...}]
```

I'm trying to figure out a wild card that would map all the attributes I don't need to change. Something like:

```
[{
  "operation": "shift",
  "spec": {
    "*": {
      "a": "[&1].a1",
      "b": "[&1].b1",
      "c": "[&1].c1",
      "*": {
        "@": "&"
      }
    }
  }
}]
```

Where:

```
"*": {
        "@": "&"
      }
```

Would work as a wildcard for all the fields I don't need to update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spec

```
[{
  "operation": "shift",
  "spec": {
    "*": {
      "a": "[&1].a1",
      "b": "[&1].b1",
      "c": "[&1].c1",
      "*": "[&1].&"
    }
  }
}]
```

Comment: Thank you! I ended up figuring out.